# How to add ContextMenu to the system tray icon programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, right-click, trayicon

I want to programmatically add a context menu to my tray icon, so that when I right-click on the tray icon, it should show me the menu.How should I write the right-click event handler for my tray icon?

I have tried the below:

```
private void Icon_MouseRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)  // shows error ate button
 {
   return;
 }
 if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
 {
   // code for adding context menu
 }
}
```

Declared Eventhandler as,

```
NotifyIcon.MouseRightClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(NotifyIcon_MouseRightClick);
```

Comment: Have you searched/tried anything?

Comment: @wudzik posted the code which I tried.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Context menu on right-click is automatic, no need to handle it.  Just build your menu and assign it to [NotifyIcon.ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx).

Comment: how to handle showing context menu with left-click?