# Detect right mouse click on NotifyIcon in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, click, right-click, notifyicon

I´m trying to open a small WPF application when right clicking on a NotifyIcon.
I added the NotifyIcon by adding the System.Windows.Forms to the resources and this lines:

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"C:\...\icon.ico");
ni.Visible = true;
```

The way I´ve tried to implement the right click event:

```
ni.Click += delegate (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Equals(MouseButtons.Right))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Haha", "haha", MessageBoxButton.OK);
  }
}
```

Both code snippets are in the MainWindow() function.

Comment: Do you want to [show context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17946380/1997232)?

Comment: Try to use `MouseClick` (or some other mouse event) instead of `Click`.

Comment: Yes it is the context menu, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add ContextMenu to the system tray icon programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946380/how-to-add-contextmenu-to-the-system-tray-icon-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the [context menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_NotifyIcon_ContextMenu)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
}
```